# Rails 4: form_for with nested resource and without

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my app, when a regular user logs in, they are dropped in on a dashboard that displays Service Requests for the company they `belong_to`.

When an admin logs in, they are dropped onto a dashboard that displays all of the company logos that can login and file Service Requests.

The views between a regular user and an admin user are virtually the exact same, outside of one or two entities on the form (which are controlled via `cancan`). So I am trying to be able to use the same form for if an admin creates an SR or a regular user creates an SR.

Routes.rb:

```
  resources :service_requests do
    resources :notes
  end

  namespace :admin do
    get '', to: 'dashboard#index', as: '/'

    resources :companies do
      resources :service_requests, only: [:index, :new]
    end
  end
```

If an admin logs in and clicks on a company logo and clicks to create a new SR, the route is `/admin/companies/1/service_requests/new`. If a regular user logs in it is, `/service_requests/new`. I am just slightly confused on how to reuse the same form for both the admin and non-admin side. Because I am setting the `company_id` on the SR in my create resource in the `ServiceRequestsController`

Comment: Wouldn't the creation be handled by `admin/companies/1/service_requests` route?

Comment: @ManojMonga - Im not sure how it would since the route is different depending on if you are in the admin view vs the normal user view

Answer (score 0):

I do something like the following to use the same form on an `admin` and a `not admin` using `cancan`

```
#models/ability.rb
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    if user.is_admin? #replace this by something that returns true if logged-in user is admin
      can :generate_this_form_fields, User
      # ^ normally can -> points to a method in the controller, but you can
      # create one even if you're not validating any method, just so you could use it anywhere
    end
  end
end
```

While on the view file where your form is, something like

```
#views/form.html.erb
<%= form_tag ... %>
  <% if can? :generate_this_form_fields, User %>
    This is where the fields are displayed if admin account
  <% else %>
    This is where the fields are displayed if not admin
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Actually in the view, you could just use

```
<% if current_user.is_admin? %>
```

And not

```
<% if can? :generate_this_form_fields, User %>
```

But I've made the example in such a way that might fit to what you're trying to solve.
Hope this helps. Cheers!